# How to create dynamic Seq<Column> in java

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataset

I want to create a Dataset out of another one but only with some specific columns and I would like to use the `dataset.select()` function instead of creating a dynamic sql query who select from this dataset the columns I need.

I have found that using `JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(asList(new Column("value1"), new Column("value2")))` I can create a `Set<Column>` but how can I do it dynamic? because I've tried this.

```
List<Column> filterColumns = new ArrayList<>();
for (ColumnMetadata field : fields) {
    filterColumns.add(new Column(field.getFieldName()));
}  
dataset.select(JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(asList(filterColumns)))
```

But this doesn't work and the compiler said `no suitable method found for select(Buffer<List<Column>>)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use it like below with list.

```
dataset.select(JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(filterColumns));
```

or like this with seq.

```
dataset.select(JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(filterColumns).seq());
```